# Weird Lazy Casting Behaviour for character in Java 11

Tags: java, casting, java-11, twos-complement

Can someone kindly explain the casting behaviour I illustrated below?

Code

```java
char charo = (char) -1;
System.out.println(charo);
System.out.println((short) charo);
System.out.println((int) charo);
```

Expected Output

```
?
-1
-1
```

Actual Output

```
?
-1
65535
```

As observed, when -1 is cast to `char` & back to `short`, it remembers what it was (which is -1) whereas when cast to an `int` it is 65535. I'd expected charo to be 65535 due to underflow upon casting to `char` since `char` only holds positive values.

Is there some sort of lazy casting behaviour I'm missing out? What is happening under the hood?

EDIT 1: Added expected output to illustrate my misconception

Comment: It does "remember"? Nope. `(short) (char) 65535` returns `-1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `int` value `-1` is equivalent to `0xFFFF_FFFF` in the [Two’s Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation. When casting it to a `char`, you’re cutting off the upper bits, ending up at `0xFFFF` or rather `'\uFFFF'`.

It’s important to keep in mind that when you do `System.out.println(charo);` you’re ending up at a different method than the other print statements, as a `char` does not only have a different value range than `short` or `int`, but also different semantics.

When you cast `0xFFFF` to `short`, the value doesn’t change, but `0xFFFF` is exactly `-1` in the 16 bit [Two’s Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation. On the other hand, when you cast it to `int`, the value gets zero extended to `0x0000_FFFF` which equals to `65535`.

That’s the way to explain it in terms of the `short`, `char`, and `int` datatypes, but since you also asked “What is happening under the hood?”, it’s worth pointing out that this not how Java actually works.

In Java, all arithmetic involving `byte`, `short`, `char`, or `int` is done using `int`. Even local variables of any of these types are actually `int` variables on the bytecode level. In fact, the same applies to `boolean` variables but the Java language does not allow us to exploit this for arithmetic.

So the code

```java
char charo = (char)-1;
System.out.println(charo);
System.out.println((short)charo);
System.out.println((int)charo);
```

actually compiles to the same as

```java
int charo = (char)-1;
System.out.println(charo); // but invoking println(char)
System.out.println((short)charo);
System.out.println(charo);
```

or

```java
int charo = 0x0000_FFFF;
System.out.println(charo); // but invoking println(char)
System.out.println((short)charo);
System.out.println(charo);
```

A said at the beginning, the first `println` ends up at a different method, responsible for the different semantics. The compile-time type of the variable only matters insofar as it made the compiler select the different method.

When always maintaining all 32 bits of a value, a cast to `char` has the effect of setting the upper 16 bits to zero. So the result of `(char)-1` is `0x0000_FFFF` and this operation is even done at compile-time already. So the first statement assigns the constant `0xFFFF` to a variable.

The next statement invokes the `println(char)` method. No conversion is involved at the caller’s side.

The other two invocations end up at `println(int)` and here, the cast to `short` is actually modifying the value. It has the effect of sign-extending a `short` value to an `int` value, which means, the 15th bit is copied over to the upper 16 bits. So for `0x...._FFFF`, the 15th bit is a one, so all upper bits are set to one, ending up at `0xFFFF_FFFF`, which is the `int` value `-1` when using [Two’s Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

The final result is in line with the first explanation given above, reasoning about the value ranges of `char`, `short`, and `int`. For a lot of scenarios, explanations on that level are sufficient. But you might notice that there is no `println(short)` method, so to understand why `println(int)` is sufficient for printing `short` (or `byte`) values, it’s necessary to know what’s really going on.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why. Turns out there is no such behaviour though it appears to be.

`charo` is `65535` under the hood. When it is cast to `short` it is still `-1` not because it remembers what it was but as a result of overflow.

`short`s have a max value of 32767. `65535 - 32767 = 32768`. By counting up from and including `-32768` for `32768` steps, we arrive at `-1` again. Thus it appears to remember what it was but it is not the case. It's all normal casting behaviour under the hood.

Thank you Johannes Kuhn for your comment.